# Removing or hiding the Coupon Field in the Cart page - WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Currently I have coupons that get applied automatically based on a functions.php script I made. I'm trying to remove the Coupon Field entirely from the Cart page but can't figure out how to. I tried the script mentioned elsewhere as shown below:

```
    / hide coupon field on cart page
function hide_coupon_field_on_cart( $enabled ) {
    if ( is_cart() ) {
        $enabled = false;
    }
    return $enabled;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_coupons_enabled', 'hide_coupon_field_on_cart' );
```

The problem is since this disables the coupons while in the cart then it also removes the discounts I created for the customer and won't show any of their discount on the Cart page. It would confuse the customers. How else can I hide or remove this Apply Coupon field on the Cart page? Would I need to use CSS or create a child theme for the cart file?

Is there any hook I could use to just use a remove_action on the hook like there is on the checkout page?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This can be done in 2 ways: overriding the right woocommerce template via your theme or hiding it with some CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this CSS code:

```
.woocommerce #content table.cart td.actions .coupon, .woocommerce table.cart td.actions .coupon, .woocommerce-page #content table.cart td.actions .coupon, .woocommerce-page table.cart td.actions .coupon {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: There's a setting in WooCommerce to remove the field from appearing.

Answer (score 0):

As with most things in woocommerce we can hide it easily through CSS. The answer by Ali did not work for me though. If you're using .woocommerce-info for other stuff on your cart/checkout, you can try to remove that class. The code below does the job for my application.

```
/* https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54695722 */    
.woocommerce-checkout .coupon-wrapper .woocommerce-info {
        display: none;
    }
```

Please note though that this does not disable or prevent users from adding coupons. People with some tech knowledge can still work around this by inspecting the page and disable the css rule to then apply coupons regardless. This code just hides the field for regular users.

The field may also show up during initial page load depending on cache settings and if the css is served critical or not. Please use at your own discretion.

Remember to purge your cache.